# ¿Qué es un "angla" en la canción "Burbujas de amor" de Juan Luis Guerra?

Tags: significado, letras-de-canciones, república-dominicana

Estaba escuchando a Juan Luis Guerra cantando *Quisiera ser un pez* cuando oí un verso que no entendí:

> Canta corazón
>
> con un **angla** imprescindible de ilusión
>
> Sueña corazón
>
> no te nubles de amargura

([letra completa](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=968004))

No sé que es un "angla". El DRAE dice que es algo inglés:

> **[anglo, gla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2eMpGSA)**
>
> Del lat. Anglus.
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: De una tribu germánica que en los siglos V y VI se estableció en Inglaterra. U. t. c. s.
> 2. adj. inglés (‖ natural de Inglaterra). U. t. c. s.
> 3. adj. inglés (‖ perteneciente a Inglaterra).
> 4. adj. anglosajón (‖ perteneciente a la lengua anglosajona). Léxico anglo.
> 5. m. anglosajón (‖ lengua).

Pero en el contexto de la canción a mí no me parece que sea esto. Y más sabiendo que en la letra subyace una connotación sexual.

Entiendo que es una palabra de jerga de República Dominicana, país de donde es el cantante, pero lo mismo en otros países también se conoce.

Comment: Versiones de la letra que dicen [_ancla_](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=131876) (_anchor_) de hecho son más frecuentes.

Comment: No sé si hay un dominicano para corroborar que _angla_ sea una manera común de decir _ancla_.

Comment: Casi alcanzo a leer "ancla": http://mlm-s2-p.mlstatic.com/juan-luis-guerra-y-440-bachata-rosa-cd-raro-canadiense-bvf-22190-MLM20224532135_012015-F.jpg (La canción se llama Burbujas de Amor)

Comment: La palabra correcta es ancla, puedes buscar la letra de la misma canción en otros sitios y lo comprobarás. Incluso, Natalia Lafourcade ha hecho un cover de ese tema y ha incluido la letra del mismo en su pagina web:
http://natalialafourcadeyo.com/sitio/letras/otras/burbujas-de-amor/

Comment: Caramba, mira que busqué y siempre encontraba _angla_. @Rodrigo gran hallazgo, aunque pequeñito se ve que no es una G (podría ser cualquier otra letra redondita, jeje).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because se basa en un fallo en la búsqueda de la letra de la canción.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fallo mío: la palabra es **ancla**, no <strike>**angla**</strike>.

> Canta corazón
>
> con un **ancla** imprescindible de ilusión
>
> Sueña corazón
>
> no te nubles de amargura

Comment: Es rara la figura. Para mí un ancla te amarra, mientras que una ilusión te libera.

Comment: @Rodrigo con cuanta frecuencia el amor se canta como una condena